# c# How to refresh a datagrid when a record is added

Tags: c#, sql, datagridview

I am having trouble refreshing my datagrid after i add a record. I have tried a few things from other tutorials but cant seam to get it working or figures out where i am going wrong.

Thanks in advance.

```
 private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constring);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
            da.InsertCommand = new SqlCommand(cmdInsert, con);



            try
            {
                if (isvalid(textEmail.Text))
                {
                    da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@firstName", SqlDbType.VarChar);
                    da.InsertCommand.Parameters["@firstName"].Value = textFirstName.Text.Trim();
                    da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@surname", SqlDbType.VarChar);
                    da.InsertCommand.Parameters["@surname"].Value = textSurname.Text.Trim();
                    da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@email", SqlDbType.VarChar);
                    da.InsertCommand.Parameters["@email"].Value = textEmail.Text.Trim();
                    da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@phone", SqlDbType.VarChar);
                    da.InsertCommand.Parameters["@phone"].Value = textPhone.Text.Trim();
                    da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@mobile", SqlDbType.VarChar);
                    da.InsertCommand.Parameters["@mobile"].Value = textMobile.Text.Trim();

                    con.Open();
                    da.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    MessageBox.Show("Customer Added");
                    con.Close();
                    clearboxes();
                    customerDataSet.Clear();
                    dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
                    customerTableAdapter.Fill(customerDataSet.Customer);
                    dataGridView1.DataSource = customerDataSet.Customer;


                }
                else
                {
                    textEmail.BackColor = Color.Red;
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());

            }
        }
```

Comment: From the MSDN documentation about DataGrid.DataSource: "At run time, use the SetDataBinding method to set the DataSource and DataMember properties." Perhaps you should try this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There **should be a function that will have a select statement on that particular table** in which  you have just inserted the record..

**Call** that function **after every insert/update/delete operations** which will give you the updated data present in database.

Comment: So call the cmdselect which holds "Select * from (Table)"?

Comment: yes you can create a separate function like BindGrid() which will hve a select command and call it after every insert/update/delete operation i.e. after firing ExecuteNonquery() command

Comment: Thank you makes alot more sense now

Answer (score 0):

Can you please elaborate why do you want to refresh the datagrid?
Yes, there could be a number of reasons for refreshing and specifying yours would help us to answer your query.

Well as per my understanding till now, I could suggest you to add the operation/function that you wish to perform after the statement that marks a record to be added to the grid.

Comment: I am just looking to update the datagrids information whenever their is a change where it be add delete update, it would populate the real time data.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who gets stuck with a similar problem this is how i managed to get round it. P.S. i am no expert so their is probably an easier / better way of doing it but here is the code and thanks to everyone for their input.

```
 public void binddata()
        {

            try
            {
                customerDataSetBindingSource.DataSource = cmdselect;
                dataGridView1.DataSource = customerDataSetBindingSource;

                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constring);
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
                da.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand(cmdselect, con);

                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                dt.Locale = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
                da.Fill(dt);
                dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;


                MessageBox.Show("Data Updated");
                con.Close();

            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }
        }



        private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constring);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
            da.InsertCommand = new SqlCommand(cmdInsert, con);



            try
            {
                if (isvalid(textEmail.Text))
                {
                    da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@firstName", SqlDbType.VarChar);
                    da.InsertCommand.Parameters["@firstName"].Value = textFirstName.Text.Trim();
                    da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@surname", SqlDbType.VarChar);
                    da.InsertCommand.Parameters["@surname"].Value = textSurname.Text.Trim();
                    da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@email", SqlDbType.VarChar);
                    da.InsertCommand.Parameters["@email"].Value = textEmail.Text.Trim();
                    da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@phone", SqlDbType.VarChar);
                    da.InsertCommand.Parameters["@phone"].Value = textPhone.Text.Trim();
                    da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@mobile", SqlDbType.VarChar);
                    da.InsertCommand.Parameters["@mobile"].Value = textMobile.Text.Trim();

                    con.Open();
                    da.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    MessageBox.Show("Customer Added");
                    con.Close();
                    clearboxes();
                    binddata();

                }
                else
                {
                    textEmail.BackColor = Color.Red;
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());

            }
        }
```